# Javascript -- How to save a txt file with HTA

Tags: javascript, hta

I am creating an HTA application that sits on a shared drive.  I have a section in which the app generates a report txt file and should allow the user to save it.

I'd like the user to be able to pick where to save it and what to call it, as you would any time you save a file, but I can't figure out how to accomplish it.  The best way I've come up with so far is to save the file, offer it up for download so they can pick a location that suits them (and a name), and then delete the automatically saved version afterward.  This sounds hacky and more clunky than it should.  Is there a better way?

EDIT: Commenter asked for the code I used to serve the download:

I had a textarea in the html that contains the report text --

```
<textarea id="reportText" class="col-md-12 form-control"></textarea>
```

Then a save file button:

```
<a class="btn btn-success" id="saveReportBtn">Save File</a>
```

When generating the report, the code adds the href and download attributes to the "Save File" button:

```
document.getElementById('saveReportBtn').href = "data:text/plain, TEST";
document.getElementById('saveReportBtn').setAttributeNS(null, "download", "");
```

Yet, nothing happens when I click the button.  I also tried giving download a recommended filename, (null, "download", "myFile.txt").

Comment: _"I have a section in which the app generates a report txt file"_ Is the file generated from text within the current `document` ? Can you include `html`, `javascript` tried at Question ?

Comment: It's just generating a long string of text and holding it in a variable, currently.  When I save things, I save them with an ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").  That all works fine, but I need to figure out a way to allow the user to select the directory and name to save to.

Comment: You could utilize `a` element, `download` attribute, see post

Comment: [`BrowseForFolder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774065%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=jscript#code-snippet-1) might be useful?

Comment: BrowseForFolder did the trick, the problem is, I get a "Permission Denied" error when trying to save anywhere "above" the folder the application is in, which kind of defeats the purpose.  I've resigned to asking the user for a file name to save as and then saving it in an "Exports" folder in the directory the application is in.  Not ideal, but I think this is just a purposeful limitation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `a` element, `download` attribute, with `href` attribute set to `objectURL` or `data URI` of file. The `Save File` dialog should display when user clicks `a` element , where user can name file and select where to save file at user filesystem

```js
var a = document.getElementById("saveReportBtn");
var textarea = document.getElementById("reportText");
  
a.addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.href = "data:application/octet-stream," + encodeURIComponent(textarea.value);
  // this.download = "";
});
```

```html
<textarea id="reportText" class="col-md-12 form-control"></textarea>
<a href="" class="btn btn-success" id="saveReportBtn">Save File</a>
```

jsfiddle using `download` attribute https://jsfiddle.net/h51dhdgn/ ; see [`download`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download)

Comment: Sadly, this didn't work with HTA, though it does work in browser for me.  Not quite sure if this is an purposeful HTA limitation or an IE engine overlook.

Comment: @linus72982 _"Sadly, this didn't work with HTA"_ Can you include `HTA` tried at Question ?

Comment: I added it to the question.

Comment: @linus72982 `a` element appears to have `id` `"saveFileBtn"` though see `document.getElementById('saveReportBtn')` ? Try changing selector at `document.getElementById()` to `"saveFileBtn"` ? Or are the different selectors a typographical error ?

Comment: Yeah, I typed it out incorrectly here (didn't copy/paste), but I looked at the commented out lines in my code and the id's are correct.

Comment: I fear this might be due to my meta tag using IE9 instead of edge.  I use the IE9 meta tag because the others don't listen to some of the HTA:APPLICATION tags I need.

Comment: See updated post. ie9 does not appear to support `download` attribute http://caniuse.com/#feat=download . A workaround could possibly be to use `"application/octet-stream"` MIME type at `data URI` at `href`